# Как в Spring записать выполняемый SQL запрос?

Tags: java, spring

В настоящих серверах приложений существует возможность записать в лог исполняемый SQL запрос для дальнейшего анализа. Какой параметр необходимо  инициализировать в  мутных  параметрах Spring  что бы записать  исполняемый  SQL запрос в файл?

Comment: Слишком абстрактный вопрос. Нужно более детальное описание. Что используешь hibernate, jpa, jdbc? Или может быть тебе достаточно настроить logback.xml на уровень debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый простой способ вывести стандартные запросы - это добавить в application.properties следующее:

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Чтобы украсить или красиво распечатать SQL, можно добавить:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```